# CSS - display elements in columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is there a way (maybe flex, I couldn't find solution) to display for example 5 elements (A,B,C,D,E) in columns verticaly with CSS?
like this:

```
A  C  E
B  D
```

I do not want to reorder elements in html.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/columns

Comment: Please show how you plan to write the default html

Comment: @Barto This is a sample code i have tried https://codepen.io/Merajkhan/pen/QXGeZj

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css+multiple-columns

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div class="test">
    <Span>A</Span>
    <Span>B</Span>
    <Span>C</Span>
    <Span>D</Span>
    <Span>E</Span>
</div>

.test {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I see:

1. columns:3 solution is sorting elements in rows not columns
2. display:flex; flex-direction: column; solution is quite good but it needs
   height to be set so it's in most cases unusable

Only real solution I found is js script, for example: https://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html